# how to change app theme in runtime in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In my simple project , there is a button to change theme form light to dark and vice versa as below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<bool> load(String key, bool defaultValue) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool state = prefs.getBool(key) ?? defaultValue;
    return state;
  }

  Future<void> save(String key, bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  bool state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    load("themeKey", false).then((bool value) {
      state = value;
    });
    debugPrint(
        "..............state is : " + state.toString() + "...............");
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: state ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("change"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                state = !state;
              });
              save("themeKey", state);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to save the current theme state for the next app launch , but there is a problem it seems that app loads before shared preference loads so i am getting this **exception**:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on C1905 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 8045): ..............state is : null...............
I/flutter ( 8045): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8045): The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: MyAppState#6774f):
I/flutter ( 8045): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
I/flutter ( 8045): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 8045): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 8045): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 8045):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 8045): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8045): #0      MyAppState.build (package:test_shared_preferenced/main.dart:36:14)
I/flutter ( 8045): #1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3787:27)
I/flutter ( 8045): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3699:15)
I/flutter ( 8045): #3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 8045): #4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
I/flutter ( 8045): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3826:11)
I/flutter ( 8045): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
I/flutter ( 8045): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 8045): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 8045): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:909:16)
I/flutter ( 8045): #10     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:880:5)
I/flutter ( 8045): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:826:17)
I/flutter ( 8045): #12     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2266:19)
I/flutter ( 8045): #13     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:825:13)
I/flutter ( 8045): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:712:7)
I/flutter ( 8045): #15     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:756:7)
I/flutter ( 8045): #16     main (package:test_shared_preferenced/main.dart:5:16)
I/flutter ( 8045): #17     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:289:19)
I/flutter ( 8045): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter ( 8045): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

so what should i do in this situation , please help

Comment: state is return null, change condition to:
```Dart
 return MaterialApp(
      theme: state == null ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark(),
...)```

Comment: @EdgarHuamani What you are trying to suggest will prevent the null value error, but not properly take into account the user's theme preference. The vast majority of the time state will not have been set before this code is executed. This means it will default to the light theme regardless of how the user preference is set. It would be better to set the theme once load future completes and the theme preference is known.

Comment: I want to make execution wait for load method to finish , how can i achieve this  ,please

Comment: @Stephen I have only answered how to solve the error that the log shows. You're right, the `ThemeData.light ()` will always be selected, @Hasan you can choose to use `FutureBuilder` I think you already have a response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method is returns a `Future` that will run asynchronously from the rest of your code. When execution reaches `debugPrint` or the subsequent return statement, you cannot be guaranteed that the `then` block has completed its execution. The error you are receiving confirms this. The `state` boolean has not been set to a value yet - it is still null.

Using a `FutureBuilder` can help you handle cases where you are waiting on a `Future` to build your widget tree.

https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures is worthwhile reading.

Comment: It works perfectly with FutureBuilder , thank you very much